# Android Firebase OnDataChange not getting triggered

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

So I'm trying to create a listener that will advertise the activity when a new entry is added to my database in Firebase like this:

```
public void dataListener() {
    Query lastQuery = mDatabase.child("id").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    lastQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("ChildAdded",dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString());
            getAddedUpdates(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("ChildError",databaseError.toString());
        }
    });
```

I'm calling this dataListener`onCreate` but nothing happens, and by that I mean, when I added a new entry on another phone this isn't triggered, even thought the data is being inserted (when i reload the app using a singleEeventListener in another method the data is received)

[image]

All fields are Text (Strings)

Comment: check firebase database rules in both read and write true.

Comment: and alos check mDatabase is not a null.

Comment: @AndroidTeam both read and write are true and the database is indeed not null.

Comment: provide your database structure.

Comment: Alright, done, there is no authentication needed for now.

Comment: i don't see mp field into database

Comment: That was indeed an error but it's still not getting triggered, will update the question with "id" instead of "mp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location is wrong, you need to change this:

```
Query lastQuery = mDatabase.child("id").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

into this:

```
 DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 Query lastQuery=ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

the snapshot is at the root node then you will be able to order the keys and retrieve the last one.

The `child("id")` does not have any key under it, example:

```
id
 pushid
   name: peter
```

The `child'("id")` is equal to a randomid then you can do this:

```
Query lastQuery=ref.orderByChild("id").equalTo(key_here)
```

Comment: My mDatabase is the same as your ref. Tried mDatabase.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);

Seems to be working at least the first call, but I think I got the concept, thank you.

Comment: yes it did not work because the child id is equal to an id and does not have a child(as I showed in the example). Okay that's great!